How can I perform CRUD operation on a table present in my Google Bigquery dataset using Apache NiFi
I need to find a way to perform Create, Insert, Update, Delete, and Merge operations on the table in BigQuery using Apache NiFi.
Current Process:

I am using the putbigquery processor to read the content of a flowfile and insert it into a table within a dataset in Google BigQuery.
Currently, I am passing the data as a CSV formatted file and using a CSVReader controller service, which is configured in the RecordReader property of the putbigquery processor to parse the incoming data and insert it.

If anyone has ideas on how to implement this, please share your approach it will be helpful for me. Thanks in advance!

Use can use record oriented processors like to update the record try update records.to merge the records use merge record try to configure the bin age correlation attributes etc to handle .Then partition record,split record,convert records, validate records are record oriented processors
